# Delay for popup modal on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I like this script because it's simple, but am new to JS to I'm not sure how to add a 5 second delay before showing the "welcome" greeting.

```
var hasSeenGreeting = localStorage.getItem("greeting");

if(!hasSeenGreeting){
       document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "block";
       localStorage.setItem("greeting", "true");
}

document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  localStorage.removeItem("greeting", "true");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use setTimeout(). [Here is a reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "block";
    localStorage.setItem("greeting", "true");
}, 5000); // 5 second delay in ms.
```

In the code above, I'm passing an anonymous function to the setTimeout call. Inside of that function I'm executing your code for setting the display property of your welcome div - along with setting the localStorage value.

Another way to accomplish this is to put these calls in their own function and then call it in the setTimeout. Example:

```
var showDiv = function() {
  document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "block";
  localStorage.setItem("greeting", "true")
}

setTimeout(showDiv, 5000); // 5 second delay in MS.
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/9tcwhnjc/)

Good luck!